# Trying to update php on CentOS 5.7

Tags: centos, yum, php

Apologies in advance - I'm not a good Linux user by any stretch of the imagination.

I have a CentOS 5.7 dedicated server on which I host a few websites.

I currently have php `5.2.10` installed, but I'd like to update to `5.3.9`.

I tried to update manually, and `php -v` displays `5.3.9`. However, when I `phpinfo()`, it displays 5.2.10.

**First problem**

I followed these instructions for updating PHP manually:

- Logged in as root
- `wget` the latest PHP installation
- `tar zxvf php-.....gz`
- `cd php-....`
- `./configure`
- `make`
- `apachectl stop`
- `make install`
- `apachectl start`

I also tried restarting httpd by `/usr/sbin/httpd restart`.

`php -v` shows the latest version of PHP but `phpinfo()` on a php page shows the old version.

Any idea what the problem there might be?

**Second Problem**

If I try to `yum update php`, it says this:

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
>
> Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>
> - epel: mir01.syntis.net
> - rpmforge: ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de
>
> Excluding Packages in global exclude list
>
> Finished
>
> Setting up Update Process
>
> No Match for argument: php
>
> No package `php` available.
>
> No Packages marked for Update

I've tried `yum clean all` and adding rpmforge repositories - same outcome!

So, secondly, does anyone have any idea why I can't update php from yum? I'd like to be able to do that in future so that I can quickly and easily keep php and mySQL up to date.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What are the outputs of `grep exclude /etc/yum.conf` and `yum search php`? As for the different versions, it sounds like you also need to update `httpd`'s PHP module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a repository that contains it is enabled, but this still happens, it is most likely excluded in `/etc/yum.conf`. Removing it should solve the issue.

Comment: Agreed PHP 5.3.9 is not available in the CentOS 5.7 unless you downloaded from other repo's.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling from source is the best way because it's always the latest source. When I compile php for my box it give me always a wrong name. I need to fix it manually for apache: ln -sf /usr/lib/apache2/libphp5.so /usr/lib/apache2/mod_php5.so. But it can depends on your configuration. Did you run make test after make? It should show you some more information.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried `yum update` ?
this will update all packages that are installed.

Comment: It seemed to update an awful lot... but not php!